# Replace all span tag in webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have a problem because I want replace all span in page to tag b.

Here is demo but is bad. to change all span I must click 2x on the button

Jquery:

```
$('#myButton').click(function(){
    $("span").replaceWith(function(){
        return $("<b>" + $(this).html() + "</b>");
    });
});
```

Html:

```
    <span>fdfdfd <span>hytrytryrt</span> fdfdfdf</span>

<button id="myButton">Change my link to a span</button>
```

Here is link:

http://jsfiddle.net/kXfX9/

Comment: you need to post the code in the question, don't just share  a link

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/FB3GT/2/

Comment: Arun P Johny, Thank you very much. It works: D

Answer (score 1):

I just got an idea!, Try to `reverse` the element collection and then invoke `.replaceWith()`

```
$('#myButton').click(function(){
    $($("span").get().reverse()).replaceWith(function(){
        return $("<b>" + $(this).html() + "</b>");
    });
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kXfX9/2/)

Comment: The problem is more complicated. This is just an example. There can be text.

Comment: @user2871294 If you feel anyone of the answers provided here satisfied your need, then try to click on the tick mark available with that answer in order to show your acceptance to the future visitors.. And it is not a compulsion... :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<span>fdfdfd <span>hytrytryrt</span> fdfdfdf</span>

<button id="myButton">Change my link to a span</button>

$('#myButton').click(function(){
    $("span").replaceWith(function(){
        return $("<b>" + $(this).text() + "</b>");
    });
});
```

**Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/Tm4Qv/1/

Comment: @user2871294, I have updated my answer. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have invalid markup. it should be:

```
 <span>fdfdfd</span> <span>hytrytryrt</span> <span>fdfdfdf</span>
```

and to change spans with b:

```
$('#myButton').click(function(){
$("span").each(function(){
    $(this).replaceWith("<b>" + $(this).html() + "</b>");
});});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/65RGP/)**

Comment: It will work. but it does not serve the purpose of iterating then. as this is only one span and will result in only one b tag

Answer (score 0):

Change your html like this

```
 $('#myButton').on('click',function(){
        $("span").replaceWith(function(){
            return $("<b>" + $(this).text() + "</b>");
        });
    });
```

**note**

**Prior** to **jQuery 1.9**, **.replaceWith()** would attempt to add or change nodes in the current jQuery set if the first node in the set was not connected to a document, and in those cases `return a new jQuery set` rather than the `original set.` The method might or might not have returned a new result depending on the number or connectedness of its arguments!

As of **jQuery 1.9**, `.replaceWith()` always `return the original unmodified set`. Attempting to use these methods on a node without a parent has no `effect—that` is, neither the set nor the nodes it contains are changed.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably best done with plain JavaScript, without jQuery. You simply get all the `span` elements and replace, in the DOM, each of them by a `b` element that you create, assigning the content of the `span` to it.

```
<button id="myButton" onclick="chg()">Change span to b</button> 
<script>
function chg() {
  var spans = document.getElementsByTagName('span');
  for(var i = spans.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    var b = document.createElement('b');
    b.innerHTML = spans[i].innerHTML;
    spans[i].parentNode.replaceChild(b, spans[i]);
  }
}
</script>
```

The `for` loop runs “backwards”, because the `getElementsByTagName` method returns a *live* collection of elements in tree order. So if you started from index 0, you would (in the simple example) first process the outer `span` element, and when you get at the inner one, the collection has shrunk so that it only has one member, at index 0, and the inner `span` thus won’t be processed.

This code does not copy any of the attributes of the `span` elements; if there are attributes to be retained, add code for copying them.

P.S. I suspect that real problem is essentially different from the one presented, since changing all `span` elements to `b` elements would make sense in rather special situations only, and the button text “Change my link to a span” in the question does not match the description or the code fragment at all.